# How to output different images depend on user screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example if I have two sets of images for my website, one set is low resolution, 
another set is high resolution, I to show the low res to the screen size like 1280 width users, and the others are high res images, how can I do that?
Using javascript? or any other method ? possible to define in css or html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) for that. More about media queries [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Example:

```
/* This block applies to all "screen" devices
*/
@media screen {
    .some-content {
        background-image: url(largeimage.jpg);
    }
}

/* This media query applies only to "screen" devices with
   a maximum width of 1279px (e.g., < 1280)
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
    /* Use `mediumimage.jpg` on these devices instead of the above */
    .some-content {
        background-image: url(mediumimage.jpg);
    }
}

/* This media query applies only to "screen" devices with
   a maximum width of 639px (e.g., < 640)
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
    /* Use `smallimage.jpg` on these devices instead of the above */
    .some-content {
        background-image: url(smallimage.jpg);
    }
}
```

Note the descending order of the above: First we specify for the largest device, then smaller ones, then smaller ones, so that latter queries override earlier ones (since a device with a screen of, say, 1024 pixels will match both of the first two rules).

Comment: @FatDogMark: Well, effort is required to succeed in things, yes. The short version is `some_selector { /* use large image */} @media all and (max-width: 1279px) { same_selector { /* use smaller image */} }`

Comment: so the syntax for css is @media all and (max-width: 1279px) ,for html is media='all and (max-width: 1279px)' ?  ok

Comment: @FatDogMark: Sorry, I didn't understand that question. `@media all and (max-width: 1279px)` will apply the following block on all media types (for instance, `screen` and `print`) but only on devices that are 1,279 pixels wide or smaller. So by giving a large image with no media query, then using a media query after that to give a smaller image on devices 1,279 pixels wide or smaller (e.g., < 1,280), you tell the CSS engine to use smaller images on smaller devices.

Comment: although ipad is small screen, how can i set it to high res if I used max-width:1279 show low res? I only want ipad to show high res in small screens

Comment: @FatDogMark: I don't know, I've never had to design specifically for the iPad. Might be worth asking that specific question here on SO, I'm sure there are several people who have. I seem to recall the iPad is a right PITA because it actively lies to the browser about its screen size and resolution... :-)

Comment: Another question is, I don't have a wide screen , I set the width and height depends on my macbook, so I don't know will the image be okay on wide screen? Will it become too small?

Answer (score 1):

you can design it with something like 
    body {width: 100%; height: 100%; position:relative;}

you will face this problem for browser compatibility.

define it in your css you can have any class you wish . i have done it for my website and you can have the same image working for you.