# Fixed image to the right of responsive div

Tags: html, css

I would like to position a fixed width image to the **right** of a flexible div that contains text, but I'm having some trouble when it comes to resizing. I want the image to drop **below** the text from a media query and then be flexible with the text.

[This is a hacked together jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EddieH/8KSMb/2/) of what I'd like to achieve. I have two img elements that I switch visibility on and off depending on screen width which feels dirty. Just resize the html section to see what I'm kinda trying to achieve.

Here's the above code example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
        <img class="right" src="http://i.imgur.com/ADL7NJ3b.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <p><strong>This text will wrap at the moment, but I want it to stick to it's column rather that wrap aroung the image.</strong>
        <br>
        <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga corrupti mollitia quibusdam nisi in natus aut nesciunt ipsam enim similique quaerat quisquam voluptates adipisci quas quam culpa voluptate! Eaque ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio inventore distinctio expedita suscipit rem tenetur magni adipisci ex ab neque aliquid minus reiciendis quibusdam dignissimos ullam. Facilis officiis sint culpa?</p>
        <img class="non-right" src="http://i.imgur.com/ADL7NJ3b.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully that makes sense? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to achieve a similar effect using `display: table-cell;` on an image and on the text. As far as I understood from your fiddle example - you don't need the text to overlap the image but stick to its column instead. So here we go:

```
HTML:
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Some header</h1>
        <p><strong>This text will wrap at the moment, but I want it to stick to it's column rather that wrap aroung the image.</strong>
            <br />
            <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga corrupti mollitia quibusdam nisi in natus aut nesciunt ipsam enim similique quaerat quisquam voluptates adipisci quas quam culpa voluptate! Eaque ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio inventore distinctio expedita suscipit rem tenetur magni adipisci ex ab neque aliquid minus reiciendis quibusdam dignissimos ullam. Facilis officiis sint culpa?</p>
    </div>
    <img class="right" src="http://i.imgur.com/ADL7NJ3b.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Pay attention that we only have one image and it follows the main content, not precedes it. Our task now is to make it visually stick to the top of the text.

```
CSS:
.content {
    display: table;
}
.wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This CSS [will not work in IE7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).
All that is left to do is to make the image come back to its original position on lower screens.

```
CSS:
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .content,
    .wrap,
    .right {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

The working example online can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/UBQrC/

Comment: That's the one! I'm not too worried about older browser support as it was just an exercise I set out to try understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apply your new image/small Image like this. I have used like this in my live site.

```
  @media screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width:600px) { /*Apply small Image using CSS*/}
  @media screen and (min-width:601px) and (max-width:1000px) { /* Apply large image **/}
```

OR

See this link. It may helpful.

**[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776520/how-to-output-different-images-depend-on-user-screen)**

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll use this for the images. However at the moment I'm more concerned with getting the flexible left column and fixed width right column working. I keep running into problems where the fixed with element has to be above the flexible one in the markup, but when float: none is set during @media, the order is incorrect. I'd just like the fixed width element to be below the flexible element.

Comment: Can you send fiddle ?

Comment: It was in my original post but it's a bit hard to see, oops. Ha. Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/EddieH/8KSMb/2/

Comment: Here's another example. Hopefully this helps? http://jsfiddle.net/EddieH/GVEFQ/1/